# A MySql query of listing cities

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an table `fs_city`, The system detects the country of the user for example US. then if the user types something, it will autocomplete the city names.

For example, "Ne" will give autocomplete "New York" ,"New Mexico", "Nebraska City"..etc. What I want to do is to place the cities from the given country (which is being detected) first, then list cities from other countries.

This is my current Sql query :

```
SELECT 
    ci.city_id,
    ci.country_code,
    ci.city,
    ci.region,
    co.country
FROM 
    fs_city ci,fs_country co
WHERE
    ci.city LIKE "'.$city.'%"
AND 
    ci.country_code LIKE :country
AND
    co.code = UPPER(ci.country_code)
ORDER BY 
    ci.city 
ASC LIMIT
    0,20
```

So, what I want to add to this sql query is the selection of cities from other countries, and listing them under cities from the detected country (whose country_code like :country), in a way that the total count of results is 20.

If it returned 2 cities from the my country starting with "Ne", example : "New York" and "Nebraska City", it must list 18 other cities from other countries, respecting the alphabetical order.

All this in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by fiddling with the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT ci.city_id, ci.country_code, ci.city, ci.region, co.country
FROM fs_city ci join
     fs_country co
     ON co.code = UPPER(ci.country_code)
WHERE ci.city LIKE "'.$city.'%"
ORDER BY (ci.country_code LIKE :country) DESC,
         ci.city 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

The `ORDER BY` has two expressions.  The first will return `1` when the country codes match and `0` otherwise.  The `DESC` puts the matches first.  The second is the city.

Note that I also fixed the query to use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks a lot, it works as expected I just didn't use the given (x LIKE y) in the ORDER BY clause before.

Comment: Good answer. A UNION statement may also be a less performance intensive way to achieve these results. If performance is not an issue, the query above will work fine.

Comment: @KirkLogan . . . I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean.  A `union` query is not guaranteed to return results in a particular order, which is what the OP wants.  You would still need to do an `order by`, so the `union` would only add overhead.

Comment: Well you would obviously use an ORDER BY clause on each side of the UNION statement...

Comment: @KirkLogan . . . Let me repeat, a `union` query does not guarantee the ordering of the results.  This is irrespective of `order by` clauses on subqueries.

Comment: `UNION` + `ORDER BY` is useless indeed. Maybe what Kirk has in mind is that two successive queries (`WHERE a = b` then `WHERE a != b`) could perform better than `ORDER BY (a = b)` (with a substantially large result set).